# Chrome Dev Tools Sources Blank

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I can no longer see the source to debug javascript using Chrome when browsing to localhost.  All I see is a blank tab.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. Try resetting devtools in its settings or use a different version of Chrome e.g.  Canary.

Answer (score 9):

I found some way to get it back. you can use `parent.location.reload(true)` in the console tab of inspect element window. then you can reload the page and find your scripts. generally Refreshing the page with `DevTools` open solve the issue for me.

Comment: What if I am using dev tools to debug my injected XSS script? Then doing this, refreshing, makes my injected script disappear.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug introduced by the recent Chrome update (version 73), where they also announced some new logging features.

I found the bug seems to appear on the index page in particular after changing between the script pages. The only thing fixing it, seems to be to open Chrome in a new window (not a new tab) or at least, that's how I work around this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit) on OS X. For me, the only way I could resolve the empty source file issue in DevTools was to close all instances of Chrome (remove chrome from memory) and restarting Chrome. Just opening a new window didn't do the trick. Also, I did not have to reset Chrome settings.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens in the node debugger when going to chrome://inspect. I found that by clicking on 'Open Dedicated Dev Tools for Node' works better.

I also went into the settings menu and reset the dev tools settings, and I verified that the "Group by Folder" option was checked by clicking on the three dots button.

[image]